# pagination links with ajax back button not going back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make pagination links work with ajax and updating the URL works fine but     when clicking back the URL updates but not the page

```
 $(document).on('click','.pagination ul li a',function(){
        var thisUrl = $(this).attr('href');
        $.get(thisUrl,function(data){                     
            $('.news_archive').html(
                $(data).find('.news_archive').html()
            );
            history.pushState(null, "A pagination link!", thisUrl);
        })
        return false;
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by listening for the hashChange event instead of the click:

```
$(window).hashChange(function() {
    var thisUrl = window.location.hash;
    $.get(thisUrl, function(data) {
        $('.news_archive').html(
            $(data).find('.news_archive').html()
        );
    })
});
```

And then just put a hash in your link :

```
<a href="#yourLink">Link</a>
```